# What are the advantages of SharePoint 2010 blog compared to WordPress

Tags: 2010, blog

we already have SharePoint 2010 in our company, and we are considering which blog platform to use in our company, we have the option to chose between SharePoint or WordPress.
Can you explain please the advantages of SharePoint 2010 blog compared to WordPress

Answer (score 5):

The advantages would be as I see them:

- Tighter integration into the company SharePoint platform
- Single user login for intranet / blog
- More business orientated, linked with the mysites this can be customised to show hierarchies and business structure
- Integrates with people search
- More administrator control
- Single code base, meaning less in house variety of knowledge required
- More powerful search engine

If I think of any more I will add them.

Answer (score 0):

As Hugh said, the biggest advantage for your case would be tighter integration with your already existing company site, that's one key factor that goes in favor of SharePoint blog over wordpress in your case

For a detail comparison read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2010/07/15/wordpress-versus-sharepoint-another-big-smackdown.aspx) article, I dont support all of his comment but you can get some idea